# How to keep GPS turned on (not allowing to switch it off)?

Tags: gps, anti-theft

I have bought an Anti-Theft application. The problem is that this application will not work properly if GPS is switched off. So I'm looking for a way to turn on the GPS and never turn it off (i.e. lock it so it stays on).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable turning off GPS completely, to make sure the thief can't turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Most Anti-Theft apps can turning on GPS automatically. And some Anti Theft apps has the abilty to receive a command from sms if there are no internet connection.